# How do I permanently change owner and group of a system device?

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive, devices

I am using a separate HDD as a disk for my Virtualbox machine. I have made a `vmdk` using the [tutorial](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) provided in the VirtualBox manual, but in order for the machine to run I have to constantly change the owner and group of the `/dev/sdb` device to the user I am logged in with.

Time after time permissions get reset back to `root:disk`, and I'm not certain when exactly that happens. What can I do to change the owner and group permanently or maybe to not have to do it at all?

Comment: Either you use the whole device ( /dev/sdb ) or you create a vmdk file, not both.  If you have a vmdk file then you need permissions for that file, not /dev/sdb.

Comment: @psusi, no, you need to create a vmdk in both cases, check out the docs I have linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probably simplest and best way to fix the problem is adding your user to disk group.

```
sudo adduser %user disk
```

Then logoff and login back, you should able to interact with hard drive from Virtualbox.

Comment: This solution has occurred to me, but what confused me initially was the device's permissions. They are set to `brw-rw---`, doesn't that mean that only `root` can boot from this device?

Comment: No, the second set of permissions rw- are for the group (disk).

Comment: This is a very insecure workaround, an user with root level access to all disks is just one step away from full root power. Better see [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/882686/62141).

Answer (score 1):

This overriding behavior you see is [udev](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/udev.7.html) daemon, the system service which maintains those device files. It acts at boot time and whenever a device is added or removed.

To configure permissions for that disk so VirtualBox users can have raw access to it, you have to create a rule for udev in a file under */etc/udev/rules.d/*. In your particular case, assuming your user is part of *vboxusers* group, that can be accomplished with a command like this:

```
$ echo 'ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sdb" GROUP="vboxusers"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/92-sdb-permissions.rules
```